# Will this LCD touch panel work with RPi

Tags: display, serial, driver, touchscreen

I am come across this nice looking affordable touch screen lcd panel http://za.rs-online.com/web/p/lcd-colour-displays/7812992 and was wondering if it would be compatible with the RPi. It seems as if though the module does come with an embedded driver that supports an 8 bit serial interface so I think I should be able to use the https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/LCD-Modules generic driver to interface with it sort of like they do with for example the Adafruit 1.8, am I correct in saying so? If so could someone please just confirm what connections should be made and that I will not have to add some adapter circuit or something.

I would also like to use the touch interface of this module and it does seem as if though the above drivers support touch but there is not to much detail as to how that works so I have completely no idea if this module's touch will be compatible. If someone could please just explain how touch implementation works that would also be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I have just noticed one of the displays that the github driver is compatible is a 
Watterott MI0283QT-9A which appears to have exactly the same driver as the screen that I want to use, an ILI9341. I will just have to use the 9 bit interface but that should not be a problem. I would still just like some confirmation that it will probably work and I still need a lot of info on getting touch to work.

Comment: I've recently bought a [2.8" Touch LCD](http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a1z10.1.w4004-1910804049.26.tZ4Lru&id=18453038149) from Shanghai when I was there. Not much of useful documentation but after some trial and error, I found that it uses ILI9341 and managed to get it working when I set it to 8 bit interface. Fyi, the `fbtft` driver for ili9341 is written only for 8 bit interface. I've raise then self resolved the issue [here](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/issues/118)

Answer (score 1):

1. this module requires 2.5V, and backlight needs 9.6V, you'll definitely need some elaborate power supply.
2. 18-bit wide parallel interface, I'm not sure you'll find enough pins on RasPi to interface with this module (there are a few extra control pins that should be connected somewhere as well). and using serial interface will be painfully slow.

while it might be possible to connect this LCD to RasPi, I'd very much advise against it, unless there's some other goal, like learning how to solder or getting a good grade for this project.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but could you please just tell me where those voltage requirements are listed because the RS page list the voltage requirements for the display as "-0.3 → +4.6 V dc" or is this something else? Also as can be seen in my above update there is already support for another display with the same driver as this one over SPI, or is there some other limiting factor that I am not seeing?

Comment: there's a link for a datasheet on RS page, around the last 2-3 pages there are DC power voltages with min/max limits. besides that, there are 2.8V markings in pinout table on the previous pages.

Comment: Ok, but getting the power should not be an issue because I will be powering the whole setup from a pc power supply where I will have  a 12V to regulate to 9.6V and a 5V to regulate to 2.8V